# Visual Studio tem atalho para navegar para um arquivo igual no Sublime Text, quando apertamos CTRL + P?

Tags: visual-studio

No sublime Text, podemos usar o atalho CTRL+P para digitar o nome de um arquivo e selecioná-lo diretamente, sem precisar ficar procurando ele na estrutura de pastas.

Por exemplo:

[image: Sublime TEXT CTRL + P]

Já no Visual Studio, existe algum atalho para fazer algo similar?

**Nota**: Eu uso a versão 2017 e a 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando que está procurando é o "**CTRL + ,**" ele abre uma input box como essa e você digita o nome do arquivo, assim que está digitando ele vai atualizando com as opções.

Esse comando funciona tanto na versão 2013 quanto na 2017 do Visual Studio, porém na versão 2013 você também tem a opção de usar "**CTRL + ;**".

Caso queira procurar um arquivo a partir do que ele contém, você pode usar "**Ctrl + Shift + F**", também ajuda muito.

Comment: Sensacional! Quando o projeto é grande, é um saco ficar navegando pelas pastas.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters realmente isso ajuda muito, principalmente em casos de projetos gigantescos rs